# Serializing object to XML to get list of tags named like field value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have 2 classes:

```
public class LocalizationEntry
{
    public List<TranslationPair> Translations
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class TranslationPair
{
    public string Language
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Translation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get such a XML using standard serializer?

```
<LocalizationEntry>
    <Translations>
        <EN>apple<EN>
        <PL>jabłko<PL>
        <DE>apfel<DE>
    </Translations>
</LocalizationEntry>
```

I was thinking about something like `XmlArrayItem(ElementName=this.Language)` attribute but of course this construction is illegal apart from that attribute value cannot be determined in runtime.

Thanks for any help. Surely I can use other structure, but I'm curious is it possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To customise the element names is a pain; I would forget about `XmlSerializer` here, as you'd have to use `IXmlSerializable` which is a royal pain. I'd use XElement instead:

```
var source = new LocalizationEntry {
    Translations = new List<TranslationPair> {
        new TranslationPair {Language="EN", Translation="apple"},
        new TranslationPair {Language="PL", Translation="jabłko"},
        new TranslationPair {Language="DE", Translation="apfel"},
     }
};

var el = new XElement("LocalizationEntry",
    new XElement("Translations",
        from pair in source.Translations
        select new XElement(pair.Language, pair.Translation)));

var xml = el.ToString();
```

Comment: +1 agree that IXmlSerializable is a royal pain when you can use a more cleaner approach

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)Use the XMLSerializer Object in the .NET Framework

Remember to put the Serializable Attribute on the Class Name

click this Link, i cant work out how to Add the Name of the URL sorry

Comment: You can't have per-element naming (EN/PL/DE) via this route